# Why doesn't my counter work? Java

Tags: java

I've tried running this, but printing out `circleCounter` only prints 0. If I were to put the counter code under the tester function in the bottom part, then it would work. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing out on something?

```
public class Project1 {
    public int circleCounter; // Number of non-singular circles in the file.
    public int posFirstLast;  // Indicates whether the first and last circles overlap or not.
    public double maxArea;       // Area of the largest circle (by area).
    public double minArea;       // Area of the smallest circle (by area).
    public double averageArea;   // Average area of the circles.
    public double stdArea;       // Standard deviation of area of the circles.
    public double medArea;       // Median of the area.
    public int stamp = 189375;

    public Project1() {
        // This method is complete.
    }


    public void results(String fileName) {
        MaInput F1 = new MaInput("DataFile.data");
        double x, y, rad;
        int circleCounter = 0;
        double sumArea = 0;
        Circle A = new Circle();

        while (!F1.atEOF()) {
            x = F1.readDouble();
            y = F1.readDouble();
            rad = F1.readDouble();

            circleCounter++;

            if (A.area() > maxArea) {
                maxArea = A.area();
            }

            if (A.area() < minArea) {
                minArea = A.area();
            }

            sumArea += A.area();
            averageArea = sumArea / circleCounter;

            stdArea = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(A.area() - averageArea, 2) / circleCounter));

            //Array for points
            Circle[] points = new Circle[circleCounter];
            for (int j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
                if (rad > Point.GEOMTOL) {
                    points[j] = A;
                }
            }

            posFirstLast = points[1].overlap(points[points.length]);

            //Array of areas
            double[] areas = new double[circleCounter];
            for (int i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
                if (rad > Point.GEOMTOL) {
                    areas[i] = A.area();
                }
            }

            //Bubble Sort
            for (int i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
                if (areas[i + 1] < areas[i]) {
                    double temp = areas[i + 1];
                    areas[i + 1] = areas[i];
                    areas[i] = temp;
                }
            }

            //Median
            if (areas.length % 2 == 0) {
                medArea = (0 / 5) * (areas[(areas.length / 2) - 1] + areas[areas.length / 2]);
            } else {
                medArea = (0.5) * (areas[((areas.length) - 1) / 2]);
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Project1 pleasework = new Project1();
        System.out.println("Number of (non-singular) circles: " + pleasework.circleCounter);
        System.out.println("Whether the first and last circles overlap: " + pleasework.posFirstLast);
        System.out.println("Maximum Area: " + pleasework.maxArea);
        System.out.println("Minimum Area: " + pleasework.minArea);
        System.out.println("Average Area: " + pleasework.averageArea);
        System.out.println("Standard deviation of the areas: " + pleasework.stdArea);
        System.out.println("Median of the areas: " + pleasework.medArea);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part doesn't work?  That's a lot of code to consume all at once, and it'd make it easier for yourself and us if you narrowed down which portion was giving you trouble.

Comment: it compiles ... but my counter returns 0

Comment: Which counter returns 0?

Comment: Note that you never call the results() method, which does all the computations. You probably only see the default values of all your variables.

Answer (score 2):

So, if it's *only* your `circleCounter` that's still giving you 0, then you should be aware of  shadowing your variables.

`private int circleCounter = 0;` is applicable to the global scope.

`int circleCounter = 0;` is applicable to the scope local to your method `results`.  The most local scope takes precedence with variables, so you've thus shadowed your global variable by redeclaring it here.

Simply take out that declaration and your variable won't be shadowed.

Edit:  This also presumes that you actually *call* the method, too.

Answer (score 2):

The main in your code does not invoke the results() method and hence all the default values of the fields are printed on your console i.e either 0 or 0.0(for double)
as main is the only entry point for java in your program.

Comment: so I'll need something like `pleasework.results(...)`? What would be in the brackets?

Comment: You can give any String value as my best guess is you are not using it in your program and also do assign local values to global values at teh end (having same name) so that you can see the changes because as Makato indicated above local variables take precedence above global in scope